# Cordova emulation of project keeps on failing

Tags: android, cordova

Hello I'm trying  to build a mobile app out of cordova but I have 0 knowledge on it so I read and tried documentation of cordova but it seems like I'm stuck on the emulation part after I input `cordova build` on terminal it compiles the project and notifies me that the build was a success.. But after I ran `cordova emulate android` it compiles for a few sec then gives an error message the error message is
[image]
anyone know whats the problem here?? Basically everything I've done was from the documentation of the [cordova site](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html). also my android emulator is running before I run the command `cordova emulate android`

Comment: Have you installed that app previously??

Comment: @Samal yes is that a problem?

Comment: try uninstalling it and try again it may solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried specifying the emulator to run the app with?

```
cordova run android --target=youremulatorname
```

or

```
cordova emulate android --target=youremulatorname
```

Also, check whether your emulator uses the API level between the indicated `android:minSdkVersion` and `android:targetSdkVersion` in the generated `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

The AndroidManifest.xml file can be found in

```
YourAppFolder/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml
```

You can check which API level your emulator uses through

```
SDK Manager > Tools > Manage AVDs
```

Comment: Hi may I ask what is the `youremulatorname`? is it the name of my AVD?

Comment: @KimOliveros Yes, in the `Android Virtual Device (AVD) Manager`, it's the `AVD Name`. Also, you can edit this name anytime to make your life easier when calling commands from the CLI.